# Summing a column in sql and grouping by it

Tags: sql, group-by

So basically I have the query below. I am trying to sum the second and third columns and the fourth. I am grouping by shiptoaddrressno and shiptoname. Is it possible to work out that equation in the fourth column using the original quantityshipped and extendedprice values? The calculation is off because I was summing the columns in order to make the query work.

```
declare @rundate datetime
set @rundate = '3/11/2013'


Declare @Sales table (ShipToAddressNo int, ShipToName varchar(40), SumOfQuantityShipped int, 
                        SumOfAmountShipped money, TotalDeductions float)
INSERT INTO @Sales
SELECT
    ShipToAddressNo,
    ShipToName,
    sum(QuantityShipped),
    sum(ExtendedPrice),
    (p.[Transfer Price] * QuantityShipped) +
    (p.[Profit Split Calculation 1 (Prasco Distribution Allowance)] * QuantityShipped) +
    (p.[Profit Split Calculation 2 (Share to Partner)] * QuantityShipped) +
    (p.[Profit Split Calculation 3 (Cost Adjustment)] * QuantityShipped) +
    (p.[Profit Split Calculation  (Cost Adjustment)] * QuantityShipped) +
    (p.[Net Sales Profit Split] * QuantityShipped) TotalDeductions --Sum this entire line 
FROM
    SalesSummary ss join [Product] p 
        on ss.ShortItemNo = p.SDITM
    join JDE_PRODUCTION.PRODDTA.F4101 im 
        on im.IMITM = p.SDITM
WHERE 
    InvoiceDate = @RunDate
GROUP BY
    ShipToAddressNo,
    ShipToName
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
sum((p.[Transfer Price] * QuantityShipped) +
    (p.[Profit Split Calculation 1 (Prasco Distribution Allowance)] * QuantityShipped) +
    (p.[Profit Split Calculation 2 (Share to Partner)] * QuantityShipped) +
    (p.[Profit Split Calculation 3 (Cost Adjustment)] * QuantityShipped) +
    (p.[Profit Split Calculation  (Cost Adjustment)] * QuantityShipped) +
    (p.[Net Sales Profit Split] * QuantityShipped)
   ) as TotalDeductions --Sum this entire line
```